# is there separate target for iPadOS apps?

Tags: ios, target, ipados

Does apple provide a separate target for iPad OS like iOS or watchOS as shown below.

- TARGET_OS_IOS is just for iOS
- TARGET_OS_TV is just for tvOS
- TARGET_OS_WATCH is just for watchOS

As now using iPad OS beta 13 for my app, but there is no official document from apple regarding the target for same.

Comment: No.  don't think there is separate for iPhone & iPad. U can create a universal app on the same target which will run on iPad & iPhone.